# How to put cardviews textview values in edittext in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, settext

I try to describe actually what i want to do using below image [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYChZ.png]

According to my image 2nd request details is a number of `cardviews` which is added onclick of Add button and when i click on *`editImageButton`* then all `textview` values will again put on edittext of first request details. And there are two `fragments` 1.`NewRequest` 2.`ModifyRequest` and when i open 1 fragment `editImageButton` will be invisible and in 2 fragment it will be visible. But i cant understand how to to this.Please suggest me.

Adapter Class

```
public class TravelRequestDetailAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private List<TravelRequestAddDetails> mDataset;
private RequestDetailsFragment mContext;
private RequestDetailModification modification;


static class ViewHolder {
    TextView TrDate, TrFrom, TrTo, TrAmount, TrDesc;
    ImageButton RemoveItem, editItem;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

@Override
public TravelRequestAddDetails getItem(int position) {
    return mDataset.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    try {
        mDataset.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        mContext.updateTotalAmount();
        modification.updateTotalAmount();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.travel_request_adddetails, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.TrDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TDate);
        viewHolder.TrFrom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TFrom);
        viewHolder.TrTo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TTo);
        viewHolder.TrAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TAmount);
        viewHolder.TrDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TDesc);
        viewHolder.RemoveItem = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        viewHolder.editItem = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


    viewHolder.TrDate.setText(getItem(position).getTRAVELDATE());
    viewHolder.TrFrom.setText(getItem(position).getTRAVELFROM());
    viewHolder.TrTo.setText(getItem(position).getTRAVELTO());
    viewHolder.TrAmount.setText(getItem(position).getAMOUNT());
    viewHolder.TrDesc.setText(getItem(position).getDESCRIPTION());

    viewHolder.RemoveItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeItem(position);
        }
    });


  //  viewHolder.editItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewHolder.editItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            modification.editRequest();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

public TravelRequestAddDetails getIteam(int position) {
    return mDataset.get(position);
}

public TravelRequestDetailAdapter(List<TravelRequestAddDetails> myDataset, RequestDetailsFragment mContext) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public TravelRequestDetailAdapter(List<TravelRequestAddDetails> myDataset, RequestDetailModification mContext) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
    this.modification = mContext;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}}
```

Pojo class

```
public class TravelRequestAddDetails {

@SerializedName("REIMBURSEMENT_DTL_ID")
@Expose
private Integer rEIMBURSEMENTDTLID;
@SerializedName("REIMBURSEMENT_HDR_ID")
@Expose
private Integer rEIMBURSEMENTHDRID;
@SerializedName("TRAVEL_DATE")
@Expose
private String tRAVELDATE;
@SerializedName("TRAVEL_FROM")
@Expose
private String tRAVELFROM;

@SerializedName("TRAVEL_TO")
@Expose
private String tRAVELTO;
@SerializedName("AMOUNT")
@Expose
private String aMOUNT;
@SerializedName("DESCRIPTION")
@Expose
private String dESCRIPTION;

public TravelRequestAddDetails() {
}

public TravelRequestAddDetails(String tRAVELDATE, String tRAVELFROM, String tRAVELTO, String aMOUNT, String dESCRIPTION) {
    this.tRAVELDATE = tRAVELDATE;
    this.tRAVELFROM = tRAVELFROM;
    this.tRAVELTO = tRAVELTO;
    this.aMOUNT = aMOUNT;
    this.dESCRIPTION = dESCRIPTION;
}
public Integer getREIMBURSEMENTDTLID() {
    return rEIMBURSEMENTDTLID;
}

public void setREIMBURSEMENTDTLID(Integer rEIMBURSEMENTDTLID) {
    this.rEIMBURSEMENTDTLID = rEIMBURSEMENTDTLID;
}

public Integer getREIMBURSEMENTHDRID() {
    return rEIMBURSEMENTHDRID;
}

public void setREIMBURSEMENTHDRID(Integer rEIMBURSEMENTHDRID) {
    this.rEIMBURSEMENTHDRID = rEIMBURSEMENTHDRID;
}

public String getTRAVELDATE() {
    return tRAVELDATE;
}

public String setTRAVELDATE(String tRAVELDATE) {
    this.tRAVELDATE = tRAVELDATE;
    return tRAVELDATE;
}

public String getTRAVELFROM() {
    return tRAVELFROM;
}

public String setTRAVELFROM(String tRAVELFROM) {
    this.tRAVELFROM = tRAVELFROM;
    return tRAVELFROM;
}

public String getTRAVELTO() {
    return tRAVELTO;
}

public String setTRAVELTO(String tRAVELTO) {
    this.tRAVELTO = tRAVELTO;
    return tRAVELTO;
}

public String getAMOUNT() {
    return aMOUNT;
}

public String setAMOUNT(String aMOUNT) {
    this.aMOUNT = aMOUNT;
    return aMOUNT;
}

public String getDESCRIPTION() {
    return dESCRIPTION;
}

public String setDESCRIPTION(String dESCRIPTION) {
    this.dESCRIPTION = dESCRIPTION;
    return dESCRIPTION;
}
```

ModificationFragment Class

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.travel_request, container, false);
    approverList=new ArrayList<>();
    travelRequestAddDetailses = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new TravelRequestDetailAdapter(travelRequestAddDetailses, this);
    requestDetailsList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.TravelRequestAdd);
    requestDetailsList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    LayoutInflater inflaterHeader = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflaterHeader.inflate(
            R.layout.lc_modification, requestDetailsList, false);
    requestDetailsList.addHeaderView(header);

    LayoutInflater inflaterFooter = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) inflaterFooter.inflate(
            R.layout.travel_details_footer, requestDetailsList, false);
    requestDetailsList.addFooterView(footer);
    raisedBy = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_raised);

    approver = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_approver);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wq_approver_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    circleProgressBar = (CircleProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    travelFrom = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_travel_from);
    travelTo = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_travel_to);
    travelAmount = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_amount);
    travelDesc = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc);
    remark = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.remark);
    documentList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.documentList);
    textViewTotal = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_totalAmount);





    selectDate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.raiseddate);
    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    selectTravelDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.texttravelDate);
    selectTravelDate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

    selectTravelDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectTravellingDate();
        }
    });
    imgSelectedfile = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.IVPCUploadDoc);
    imgSelectedfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openFileChooser();
        }
    });

    btn_add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (validateData(v)) {
                addRequestDetails();
                updateTotalAmount();
            }

        }
    });
    setRequestDetails();
    return rootView;
}

 public void addRequestDetails() {
    TravelRequestAddDetails obj = new TravelRequestAddDetails(selectTravelDate.getText().toString(),
            travelFrom.getText().toString(),
            travelTo.getText().toString(),
            travelAmount.getText().toString(),
            travelDesc.getText().toString());

    travelRequestAddDetailses.add(obj);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    selectTravelDate.setText("");
    travelFrom.setText("");
    travelTo.setText("");
    travelAmount.setText("");
    travelDesc.setText("");

}

public void updateTotalAmount() {
    int total = 0;
    if (travelRequestAddDetailses != null && !travelRequestAddDetailses.isEmpty()) {
        for (TravelRequestAddDetails travelRequestAddDetails : travelRequestAddDetailses) {
            total = Integer.parseInt(travelRequestAddDetails.getAMOUNT()) + total;
        }
    }
    textViewTotal.setText(total + "");
}
public void editRequest(){

    for(int i=0;i<travelRequestAddDetailses.size();i++) {
      //  selectTravelDate.setText();

    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to store your savings in some local databaase or in Shared Preferences. And then access them whenever you want them.

Comment: can u plz elaborate

Comment: Use MVC approach or Shared Preferences/Database to store your savings from EditText and then access it. Since you are using fragments then to communicate between those you will need an Interface. There are lots of tutorials or related questions on StackOverFlow. Still you want an exact answer, clearify your exact problems and what you want to achieve though. Good Luck.